# my css selector for form-control is not working

Tags: css

```
div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
    <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="POST" role="form" name="myForm" style="margin-top: 50px;">
       <div class="well">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
               <label class="Control-label col-sm-4" id=""> Email:</label>
               <label class="Control-label col-sm-4" id=""> Username:</label>
               <label class="Control-label col-sm-4" id=""> Password:</label>
          </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group ">
              <div class="input-group col-sm-12">

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email here" ng-model="Email" required/>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username here" ng-mode="Username" required/>
                      </div>

                       <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <input  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password here" ng-mode="Password" required/>
                      </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <h1> Test </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
       </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and my CSS code is :

```
.form-control{
width: 150px;
}

h1{
color:red;
}
```

Good Day mate, i am just confuse if im doing right or not. i want to resize the input on my website which defined as class "form-control" but when i do the css above nothing changes. can someone help me if my selector or wrong or my codes is? thank you

P.S the test below is just a xample if the css is being link in my editor and yes the color red is being executed

Comment: check first that your css file is attached to the page and it must come after bootstrap.css in order

Comment: Your example works for me.

Comment: Your code woks for me. is there a way to check your full page code?

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman im just  bootstrap.min.css only mate but the comment below telling me that put !important is working. but seems others said that its doesnt good to use !important in css. any alternative solutions for that?

Comment: @expert123 Edited the answer. With best practice. hope it helps

Comment: @expert123 You could(/should) look into CSS Specificity: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: !important helps you to get priority for that particular style. So to avoid "!important" we have to find out which css property is being applied in your html and edit that.
Also make sure that your css file included after the bootstrap css? if the selector is same in your css file and bootstrap css, it may help to avoid "!important".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more specific the selector, the more precedence it has. For example :

```
.mydiv .myclass {
    background-color: blue;
}

.myclass {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Even tho the red background is defined after the blue one, the first one is more specific in the class that it is applied to, and in case you have the following code, the blue background will be applied :

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <div class="myclass">
    </div>
</div>
```

So what you want to do in your case, and this is the most basic but still the better solution, is to add a class to your `form` in order to be able to specify the width of the `form-control` elements for this form :

```
<form class="form-inline cool-form">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="form-group ">
          <div class="input-group col-sm-12">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email here" ng-model="Email" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username here" ng-mode="Username" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password here" ng-mode="Password" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And then specify the width in your css :

```
.cool-form .form-control {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

**note:** *and you are missing to close your first div i.e `<div class="container">`*

```css
.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  width: 250px;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="POST" role="form" name="myForm" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label class="Control-label col-sm-4" id="">Email:</label>
            <label class="Control-label col-sm-4" id="">Username:</label>
            <label class="Control-label col-sm-4" id="">Password:</label>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group ">
              <div class="input-group col-sm-12">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email here" ng-model="Email" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username here" ng-mode="Username" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password here" ng-mode="Password" required/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <h1> Test </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: A browser-specific answer is the worst possible solution.

Answer (score -2):

You are using Bootstrap and `form-control` class is used from Bootstrap CSS.

Use (Easy way)

```
.form-control{
      width: 150px !important;
}
```

to override your code over Bootstrap CSS

The best practice -

In your case the class is `.form-control` (Bootstrap class)
To overcome this is to define new class and add new changes to your own class.

```
  .form-control-override{
          width: 150px;
    }
```

and use this `form-control-override` in your HTML code instead of `form-control`

Comment: mate thats works! can you explain more or give me some article about this "!important" thing? how and when to use it

Comment: @KamaalABOOTHALIB is der any solution for this without using !important? thanks

Comment: @KamaalABOOTHALIB You should read here more on how to use !important. This should enlighten your prowess on CSS [When to use !important](http://www.webcredible.com/blog/importance-important-css-declaration/)

Comment: @expert123 yep, create another class of your, i.e ".inputW150 {width:150px}" and add that beside class ".form-control"

Comment: @expert123 Please mark the question as answered if it resolved your query.

Comment: @ expert123 please check my solution. never follow bad practice unless you dont have any options. you can use !important its not a crime but its an anti-pattern. I think u can use !important when you have to override inline styles.

Comment: @PirateX you say editing bootstrap is harmful, and you write your answer like that - it affect all the input have that class like when you editing the bootstrap file

Comment: @HenryVarro I didnt say to edit the form control class of bootstrap. Rather create a new class with different name. Edited the answer now to avoid being misunderstood

Comment: @PirateX my comment base on your first answer, not after you edit-a-lot-after

Comment: @HenryVarro I believe in correcting myself rather than sticking to a wrong answer. Thanks for the input.